# Android studio, Java: Cannot change horizontal margin at run time (ConstraintSet.LEFT)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, margin, android-constraintlayout

As the title says, I normally use ConstraintSet to change location of a button or layout at run time, and I have a long code where it works, but I tried again on the same project, and again in a test project (below) and all I could ever change was the vertical margin. For some bizarre reason the horizontal margin is ignored. This line specifically:

```
set.connect(testLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, rootLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT, 100);
```

If it was both of them that didn't work I would consider that maybe I put it in the wrong place or something, but no, one works the other doesn't, and the only difference is one has TOP and one has LEFT, there is literally no room for error. So what gives? Here is the code of the test run, I tried one designed in xml and one designed programmatically, neither work for the LEFT case:

Main

```
package com.example.cusom_buttom_test1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //XML OBJECTS
        ConstraintLayout rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        ConstraintLayout testLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_test);

        //SET LOCATION OF testLayout
            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(rootLayout);
            set.connect(testLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, rootLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP, 500);
            set.connect(testLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, rootLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT, 100);
            set.applyTo(rootLayout);

        //CREATE NEW CONSTRAINT LAYOUT
            ConstraintLayout testLayout2 = new ConstraintLayout(this);
            testLayout2.setId(View.generateViewId());
            testLayout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            rootLayout.addView(testLayout2);

            //SET SIZE
            testLayout2.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
            testLayout2.getLayoutParams().width = 200;

            //SET LOCATION
            ConstraintSet set2 = new ConstraintSet();
            set2.clone(rootLayout);
            set2.connect(testLayout2.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 100);
            set2.connect(testLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 300);
            set2.applyTo(rootLayout);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_test"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:background="#DD1515"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you need to change it just visually, it will be better to use animation and transitionY

Comment: If it's a button with a function will the functional location also change?

Comment: yes. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

Comment: It works, thanks. I found another solution as well:
```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) testLayout.getLayoutParams();
        margins.topMargin = 100;
        margins.leftMargin = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found two answers that work, instead of using ConstraintSet, use either animate or MarginLayoutParams.

```
testLayout.animate().x(300).y(700).setDuration(0).start();
```

```
testLayout.animate().x(300).y(700).setDuration(0).start();
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) testLayout.getLayoutParams();
margins.topMargin = 100;
margins.leftMargin = 200;
```